# Compose synchronize two HorizontalPager Offset Fraction

Tags: kotlin, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-scrolling

Hallo everyone i have created a Compose function with two HorizontalPager but i wanted to synchronize the scrolling between both of them when the user scrolling left or right and i try the following Lagging then there is always a delay between them at the scrolling is there any other solution,or another way to do it
[image]

here is an Adapter as interface

```
interface ComposeSwipeTabAdapter {
    val itemCount: Int
    val currentScreenIndex: MutableStateFlow<Int>

    @Composable
    fun GetTabHeaderContent(index: Int)

    @Composable
    fun GetTabBodyContent(index: Int)
}
```

and here is my function
`

`````
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ComposeSwipeTabsViewer(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, adapter: ComposeSwipeTabAdapter, itemWidthPercentage: Float = TAB_WITH_PERCENTAGE.toFloat()) {
    val firstPagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0, initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f) {
        adapter.itemCount
    }
    val secondPagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0, initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f) {
        adapter.itemCount
    }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(firstPagerState) {
        snapshotFlow { firstPagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
            coroutineScope.launch {
                adapter.currentScreenIndex.emit(page)

            }
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = firstPagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction, key2 = secondPagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction) {
        if (firstPagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction != secondPagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction) {
            if (firstPagerState.isScrollInProgress) {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    secondPagerState.scrollToPage(firstPagerState.currentPage, firstPagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction)
                }
            } else if (secondPagerState.isScrollInProgress) {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    firstPagerState.scrollToPage(secondPagerState.currentPage, secondPagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            // Draw Header
            HorizontalPager( state = firstPagerState, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 42.dp, vertical = 8.dp), pageSpacing = 16.dp) { page ->
                adapter.GetTabHeaderContent(index = page)
            }
            //Body Content
            HorizontalPager(
                state = firstPagerState,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            ) { page ->
                adapter.GetTabBodyContent(index = page)
            }

        }
    }
}````

i tried with Box in background to calculate the drag amount also and then assign them into Pagers
`````